# Jdk1.7.0_79 how to install/configure iText7

Tags: java, itext

I have downloaded itext7 (PDF creating API) and would like to be able to use it in my java program.

When I compile it, I get the "cannot find symbol" on each part of the code coming from iText, so I guess that it is not set in CLASSPATH.

I put it like this:
SET CLASSPATH =%CLASSPATH% ;.\lib.jar  (because I put all the itext jars in \lib)

However this doesn't solve my issue. 
Anyboday who could help me?

Thank you a lot

Below are the errors got while compiling:

[image: screenshot of the errors I obtain]

Comment: set the classpath properly :
`SET CLASSPATH =%CLASSPATH% ;.\lib\*.jar;`

or use this approach :

`javac -cp ".\lib\itext7*.jar;" <your-java-file>`

add other required jar/class files in -cp argument if you need.

Comment: Hi, I tried what you said but no it is not working

Comment: better add the stacktrace which had captured on compiling the project to find put the exact problem. Also add the command you have used to compile the project.

Comment: Like I said, I did try both of your solutions, none of them solved the issue.

Comment: In any case: `.\lib.jar` is wrong; `lib` is a directory, not a jar. `.\lib\*.jar` is more correct. Also: isn't it easier to let your IDE take care of this. We have instruction videos for Eclipse, NetBeans and IntelliJ IDEA here: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/installing-itext-7 I can't remember the last time I've had to set a CLASSPATH; that's so 20th century. Why aren't you using Maven to take care of this?

Comment: plz add the exception stacktrace and which platform you are working on, whether is it linux or windows?

Comment: I don't know how to add the stacktrace, all the errors are "Cannot find symbol"

Comment: Im on Windows, and Im just using Notepad++

Comment: edit your question, copy and paste the stacktrace. Thanks.

Comment: This is simple and known classpath issue. Make sure you are using the updated/correct version of itext jar which contains all the classes you have used in your project. This is it.

Comment: I just downloaded it yesterday from the official website !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118398/discussion-between-s-k-venkat-and-tom).

Comment: I went to the chat but the person was no longer there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using Eclipse and importing iText7 as External jars, which I didn't want to do, but.... it appears that there is no other way

Answer (score 1):

The example program you found [here](http://www.jmdoudoux.fr/java/dej/chap-generation-documents.htm#generation-documents-2) is obsolete. I have tried the same in my PC and have the same problem what you had. Plz refer this [inhouse documentation for developers](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-1#1723-c01e01_helloworld.java) provided by iText for version 7.

Thanks.